# Why does my list change even outside a function and using the copy method in python?

Tags: python, list, function, copy

I wrote this simple code and I don't know why even using the copy() function and creating a copy of my list, the original one change after I apply the function. Why does this happen?

```
x=np.array([1,0,-1])
x=np.random.choice(x,50,True)
y=list()
y.append(x)

def something(y):
 a2=y.copy()
 a2[0][np.where(a2[0]==1)]=50
 return(a2)

h=something(y)
```

Comment: Because you took a _shallow_ copy, yet you have a nested structure so need a _deep_ copy

Comment: As @roganjosh said, instead of `copy()` use `deepcopy()`